# Redis client 'redis' for node js is not returning expected value

Tags: node.js, redis

i have added some geo coords using

```
redisClient.geoAdd('cabs', {longitude, latitude, member});
```

and now i am trying to retrieve cabs based on customer coords using

```
let res = await redisClient.geoRadius('cabs', {longitude:cust_lon, latitude:cust_lat}, 10, 'km', 'WITHDIST', 'WITHCOORD', 'ASC');
```

but it is only returning cab ids not the distance and coordinates `[ 'AS343DS1', 'AS343DSS' ]`

i tried the same command using redis-commander there it works fine. `georadius cabs 91.731377 26.148043 10 km WITHDIST WITHCOORD ASC` it returns

```
1) ["AS343DSS","0.0053",["91.73133641481399536","26.14801238606236211"]]
2) ["AS343DS1","0.0252",["91.73112720251083374","26.14800985134120737"]]
```